# Both server and socket reporting ECONNRESET. Whats going on?

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, poll-syscall

I have a C++ server and client.

I am using the poll() system call to monitor sockets on the server for read-ready, write-ready and errors.

For some of the connections, I see the poll() detects an ECONNRESET after sending out a bunch of data and fails midway. On the client side too, I see a ECONNRESET being reported.

So essentially both sides are reporting that the remote side closed the connection.

How can this happen?
How do I debug this? Is there any tcp layer logging that I can enable?

Comment: Have you access to Wireshark to record a packet trace and see what's going over the network?

Comment: There can be a lot of reasons why such can happen, I'd recommend using wireshark as mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please.

Comment: I've voted to delete this because it has no value, nor does it's answer without further information.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any tcp layer logging that I can enable?

The most common tool to enable you seeing what's going on at your low level IP transport channels is [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

You can inspect any packets send and received over your NIC in detail with that tool.

Another one is [tcpdump](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump) for linux systems.

Comment: Unfortunately this is in a test environment with a lot of servers. I do not have control over the machines.
Even if I did how do I capture packets exactly when this problem happens.

Comment: @siri You only need to have control over your client machine to watch the traffic.

Comment: I have a lot of traffic going over that machine. This problem happens only sometimes. A lot of connections and all of them detect socket error 104 even in a successful case after a full transfer. Only in some cases I see the connection being reset on both sides in the middle of the transfer. How do I use tcpdump to capture this scenario?

Comment: @siri Use filters, grep tools, whatever ... Sorry, I can't give better advice, it's not an easy task to capture such scenarios.